# Differences between method pointer casting rules in g++ and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pointers, methods, g++

```
struct Test
{
    typedef unsigned (Test::*MethodPtr)();
    unsigned testMethod() {}
};
typedef void (*ThreadPtr)(void *);
ThreadPtr threadPtr = reinterpret_cast<ThreadPtr>(&Test::testMethod);
```

I want to launch a thread into a class method of a particular object. I use a method pointer as the thread entry point and pass the object pointer as the only parameter. This works as I don't have any virtual declarations in my structure.

My question relates to the reinterpret_cast operation. g++ allows this, Visual Studio 2008 does not. I got around the VS2008 restrictions by memcpying the method pointer value directly into the threadPtr variable. The resulting code worked ok but it's a gruesome workaround for what should be a simple operation. Can anyone provide more elegant alternatives?

Thanks

-G

**Edit :**

Just to clarify, the warning given by gcc is as follows:

```
methodPtrTest.cpp:14: warning: converting from ‘void (Test::*)()’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’
```

Comment: You can't cast between a function pointer and a PMF. Just no.

Comment: That cast is dangerous and you should never want to do it. What exactly are you trying to work around?

Comment: I just wanted to quickly hack in some thread functionality into a test object. I'm not excessively concerned with safety, I just want the compiler to get out of my way.

Comment: @Gearoid: At least make your `testMethod` static. Then at least you're not casting between a function pointer and a PMF.

Comment: Or make a short function with the right signature: `void runmemberfn(void*) { Test().testMethod(); }` .

Comment: @Chris, I want access to the object members. That's the whole reason I'm doing this. I know I could just create a wrapper function which I can pass to the thread invocation function which then invokes the object method I want to run, but that's just too straight-forward :)

Comment: @Gearoid: I've posted an answer that allows you to do that. When you create the thread, use the instance of `Test` as your context object.

Comment: What version of G++ are you using?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5, it compiles with a warning

Comment: It sounds like a GCC 4.4 bug, it should give `invalid reinterpret_cast from type unsigned int (Test::*)() to type void (*)(void*)`

Comment: Ok, just tried pasting the error into the comment thread, some auto-formatting wiped out the details, I'll post it as an answer...

Comment: What could have posessed GCC developers to change this to a warning?

Comment: Don't know but imho, if the programmer wants to veer off the beaten track then he/she should be allowed the freedom to make those mistakes. Obviously not everyone is going to agree with this but if you want a bovine sense of saftey, stick with Java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, do this:

```
void threadMethod(void* ptr) {
    static_cast<Test*>(ptr)->testMethod();
}

ThreadPtr threadPtr = &threadMethod;
```

That way, you're dealing with a real function, not a PMF.